# Django: form is valid but is not save because no module named app is found

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a simple form to upload files. I'm using `Django 2.2.3`.

I see that my form is valid because some print statments I've made, however I'm getting an error when saving the form.

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /admineditorial/predica/add/
No module named 'app'
```

And:

```
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap> in _find_and_load_unlocked, line 965
```

I don't think it has to do something with Bootstrap. I don't know what could be happening.

**Also, I'm uploading to `/audio`, but do I need to create this folder or is it generated automatically? if not, where should I create it?**

**Proyect structure:**

```
-editorial
    |_managment.py
    |_migrations.py
    |_templates
      |_editorial
        |_index.html
      |_predicas
        |_predicas.html
      |_base.html
    |_admin.py
    |_forms.py
    |_models.py

-el_comercio_app
    |___init__.py
    |_settings.py
    |_storage_backends.py
    |_urls.py
    |_wsgi.py
```

**models.py:**

```
 class Predica(models.Model):
     audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to = u'audio/', max_length=200)
```

**views.py:**

```
# Create your views here.
def predica_upload(request):
    predicas = Predica.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PredicaUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("### Form is valid ###")
            form.save()
            print("Despues del save")
            print(form)
            return redirect('today_editorial')
        else:
            print("### Form not valid ###")
            print(form.errors)    
    else:
        form = PredicaUpload()
    return render(request, 'predicas/predicas.html', {'form': form, 'predicas': predicas})
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from editorial import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.today_editorial, name="today_editorial"),
    path('predicas',views.predica_upload, name = 'predica_upload')
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**predicas.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Subir</button>
    </form>
    {% for predica in predicas %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{predica.audio_file.url}}" alt="myvideo">
    </div>
    <p>No audios in my gallery yet :-(</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

**settings.py:**

```
"""
Django settings for el_comercio_app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from decouple import config
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl



# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'el-comercio-editoriales.herokuapp.com']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'editorial',
    'storages'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'editorial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'editorial', 'templates/'),]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media' 
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'el_comercio_app.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

default_dburl = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')

DATABASES = { 'default': config('DATABASE_URL', default=default_dburl, cast=dburl), }

####

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-PE'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'


MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'


####

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

####

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ='XXXXXX' 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ='universidad-elim-test-videos'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN='%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {    
     'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
] 
STATIC_URL='https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (           'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

**UPADTE 1**

I had a file apps.py but deleted it bacuse maybe it was causing a conflict. However, it did not solve the problem.

**apps.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EditorialConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'editorial'
```

Comment: Can you post your apps.py please?!

Comment: @HigorRossato I've deleted it, because maybe it was causing a conflict. However, it did not solve the problem. I'll put the contents of apps.py anyway,

Comment: That’s propably what your missing. Your app in INSTALLED_APS should be something like `myapp.apps.AppConfig`

Comment: admineditorial vs editorial

Comment: @gregory can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

In your INSTALLED_APPS your app should be listed like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'editorial.apps.EditorialConfig'
]
```

You can read in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your settings.py the ROOT_URLCONF is pointing to  'editorial.urls' but in your project structure I don't see the urls.py second in the error your are posting is talking about admineditorial/ directory and i don't see it in your project structure neither.